# Does this implementation of password authentication seem secure?

Tags: security, password-protection, password-hash

I am creating a web app for which I need to perform authentication securely. Reading numerous articles and posts I have come to the following conclusion with the implementation.

1. FrontEnd Password Hashing: Using bcrypt, I would hash the plain text password with a unique salt. This salt is stored on the database for each user. This #1 salted-hash is then sent to the API.
2. BackEnd Password Hashing: Using PBKDF2, the #1 salted-hash is hashed again with another unique salt producing the #2 salted-hash which is then stored in the database with #2 salt.

So in total, the database has #2 salted-hash,#1 salt, and #2 salt.

So while authorization happens, the #1 salt is then used to hash the plain-text password which creates #1 salted-hash. This then goes to the API for authorization, there we get the #2 salt from the database to create #2 salted-hash, which is then compared to the #2 salted-hash from the database to authorize.

Sorry if the question seems redundant, but I couldn't find any answers specific to the implementation. If someone could help me it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the Information Security Stack Exchange? E.g. [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66476).

Client-side password hashing is usually considered an useless and unnecessary step that does not improve security. In fact, your implementation could even have an unwanted side effet actually lowering security: [user enumeration](https://securityriskadvisors.com/blog/user-enumeration/)

Depending on how you implement the first step during authorization you could be vulnerable to user enumeration. I am assuming you don't send back a #1 salt if no matching user is found in your database:

1. Anon tries to login with an username/email that does not match to an user in your database
2. As this user does not exist, there is no corresponding #1 salt to send back
3. Your API does not send back a salt, or even worse, sends a "user not found" response. Either way, anon now knows that this username/email does not have an account

It also works the other way:

1. Anon tries to login with an username/email that does match to an
   user in your database
2. As this user does exist, the API sends back the #1 salt of this user
3. Anon now knows that this username/email has an account

To avoid this user enumeration, your API should send back a #1 salt **even** if no matching user is found, and even more, it should always send the **same** salt in response to the same username/email, or this could happen:

1. Anon tries to login with an username/email that does not match to an user in your database
2. As this user does not exist, there is no corresponding #1 salt to send back
3. Your API sends back a random salt
4. Anon tries a second time with the **same** username/email
5. Your API sends back **another** random salt not identical to the first one
6. Anon can deduce that your API made up both salts in an attempt to circumvent user enumeration

To fix that you would have to come up with a way to always send back the same salt in response to an unknown username/email tried multiple times. But it should not be the same salt for every unknown user either or anon will make the same deduction.

All in all, seems like unnecessary complexity. This is probably one of the reasons why client-side password hashing is not considered a good thing to do.